# Rails+Device; how to avoid user from becoming an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device

A basic rails5.0 app with device for user model. I added the admin column with a default false for new records. In the signup screen I have the basic fields name, email, etc. But I am concerned about someone injecting admin=TRUE to the params when the user is created.
How would you go about creating this restriction?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: May be with strong params? I guess by ***not permitting*** `admin` attribute in strong params can restrict the creation in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The direct comment of Pavan to your post is correct. Using strong parameters is one of Rails best practices.

Just filter our params, which you allow to accept:

`def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end`

and assign only those to the user object:

`@user.update(user_params)`

Comment: Thanks! for your help